# TypeError: undefined is not a function in nodejs using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am running this piece of code using Node.js:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://${server}:27017/${db}";
var username = '${user_name}';
var password = '${password}'
// Connect to the db
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if(!err) {
    console.log("successfully connected to the database");
  }else{
    console.log("Error on connecting... aborting and exiting");
    return console.dir(err);
    throw err;
   }
    db.authenticate(username, password, function(err, res) {
    var startId = 7882;
    var userCount = 100;
    var num = 235;
    var baseGeologOrig = db.collection('geologs').find({user_id:279, created_at:{$gte:new Date("2015-01-31"), $lte:new Date("2015-02-02")}}).limit(1227);
    var baseGeolog = [];    
    baseGeologOrig.forEach(function (obj) {delete obj._id;baseGeolog.push(obj);});
      
// callback
    console.log("Reached here...!");
    console.log(baseGeologOrig);
```

now when I run this piece of code I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
 at /home/Scripts/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:696:15
    at handleCallback (/home/Scripts/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:95:12)
    at /home/Scripts/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:662:22
    at handleCallback (/home/Scripts/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:244:5)
    at /home/Scripts/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:659:22
    at queryCallback (/home/Scripts/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:267:14)
    at Callbacks.emit (/home/Scripts/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:95:3)
    at null.messageHandler (/home/Scripts/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:243:23)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/Scripts/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:262:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
```

I have tested it and found out this problem is my last line of code, any idea how to solve it?

Comment: last line means which one?

Comment: baseGeologOrig.forEach(function (obj) {delete obj._id;baseGeolog.push(obj);});

Comment: can u do console.log for the obj and baseGeolog for me

Comment: ReferenceError: obj is not defined
    at /home/Scripts/MongoScript.js:28:17
    at handleCallback (/home/Scripts/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:95:12)
    at /home/Scripts/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:1320:22

Comment: at /home/Scripts/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/replset.js:565:28
    at /home/Scripts/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:1013:20
    at /home/Scripts/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/auth/scram.js:189:20
    at /home/Scripts/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:754:46
    at Callbacks.emit (/home/Scripts/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:95:3)

Comment: at null.messageHandler (/home/Scripts/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:243:23)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/Scripts/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:262:22)

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting a undefined value in the `var baseGeologOrig=`    Itself this the reason you are getting the obj value undefined please check.

Please condole log the baseGeologOrig